# IncludeApp API for real-time android analytics, when to track?

Tags: android, real-time, analytics

We are developing an android app, and i need some analytics to track usage patterns in real-time. I tested several analytics and found out that most like Google and Flury cannot work in real-time, and so far the fastest real-time android analytics I tried seems Includeapp.

Does anyone have actual experience using the Includeapp API for this purpose? For example, is it best to track fewer events to speed up things, etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includeapp tracker engine is flexible enough to track hundreds of events in
real-time. Experimentally,  the best case scenario with say 100 events
of events per second is a round-trip time of about 100-200
milliseconds. The worse case scenario, with several hundred events is
less than 4-5 seconds end-to-end.

Comment: is this true regardless of the type of android device? also, what if my app needs mostly 100 events but there are parts of the code that it tracks 1000 events? do you think it's best to limit the amount?